# Determine the value of $k$ if $x-2$ is a factor of $2x^3-kx^2+5x-3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've divided using synthetic division but how would I solve for $k$?

Answer (score 8):

Hint: put $\,f(x)=2x^3-kx^2+5x-3\,$ , then $\,(x-2)\,$ is a factor of $\,f(x)\iff f(2)=0\,$ .

Answer (score 3):

That $(x - 2)$ is a factor of $p(x) = 2x^3 - kx^2 + 5x - 3$ means exactly that
$$
p(2) = 0.
$$
That is you want to solve the equation:
$$
0 = p(2) = 2\cdot 2^3 - k2^2 + 5\cdot 2 - 3
$$
for $k$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: @jasminder88: Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Since $(x-2)$ is a factor of the function $$f(x) = 2x^3 - kx^2 + 5x - 3$$, we know that $2$ is a zero of the function: solve for $k$ knowing $f(2) = 0$. What this means is that $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 2$:

$$f(2) = 2(2)^3 - k(2)^2 + 5(2) - 3 = 0 \quad \implies \quad k = \quad?\tag{$*$}$$

So simplify the equation $(*)$. You have an equation in *one unknown*, where the unknown to solve for is $k$. At this point, it's fairly straightforward!

---

Added: Usually there are quick and "dirty" (and *smart*) "tricks" to try before using *brute force* factoring in problems like this. This problem can be done by trying to factor, given the factor $(x - 2)$, and in doing so, it is possible to determine out $k$ must then be, but when there's a *simpler approach*, go for it!

- Any time you're given a factor, you can immediately discern a "*zero*" of the function: if $\,(x - a)\,$ is a known factor, where $a$ is some number, then $\,x = a\,$ and $f\,(a) = 0.$ (That's why $x = a$ is a called a "zero" of the function.)

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome, jasminder88!

Answer (score 1):

Since $(x-2)$ is a factor of $f(x)$, $f(2) = 0$.

Therefore : $ 2.2^3 - k.2^2 + 5.2 - 3 = 0 $

=> $4k = 23 => k = 23/4$

Hope this is clear enough !

Answer (score 1):

You found that 2 is a zero, so plugging in 2 for x in f(x) must make the whole polynomial equal to 0. Then your equation becomes a lot simpler using algebra and becomes just 23 - 4k = 0. Solving for k, you get k = 23/4. This video has more help for solving synthetic division problems, if you want more examples:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIX0VvwfEko 
 Good luck!